# Select option with arrow keys

Tags: ruby, terminal

Does the command prompt support selection using the arrow keys + <kbd>Enter</kbd>? I'm creating a Ruby program that runs in the command prompt and was wondering if I can achieve something that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the curses library?

Comment: @SomeGuy doesn't work correctly on my windows. So if N1ghtshade3 want *nix only - curses might be good.